# Cython Memoryview Seg Fault

Tags: python, c, cython

I am running into a segmentation fault when trying using Cython's memoryview. This is my code:

```
def fock_build_init_with_inputs(tei_ints):

     # set the number of orbitals
     norb = tei_ints.shape[0]

     # get memory view of TEIs
     cdef double[:,:,:,::1] tei_memview  = tei_ints

     # get index pairs
     prep_ipss_serial(norb, &tei_memview[0,0,0,0])

void prep_ipss_serial(const int n, const double * const tei) {

   int p, q, r, s, np;
   double maxval;

   const double thresh = 1.0e-9;

   // first we count the number of index pairs with above-threshold integrals
   np = 0;
   for (q = 0; q < n; q++)
     for (p = q; p < n; p++) {
       maxval = 0.0;
       for (s = 0; s < n; s++)
         for (r = s; r < n; r++) {
           maxval = fmax( maxval, fabs( tei[ r + n*s + n*n*p + n*n*n*q ] ) );
         }
       if ( maxval > thresh )
         np++;
     }
   ipss_np = np;
```

When I run the code by calling the first function with an input of numpy.zeros([n,n,n,n]), I run into a segmentation fault when n exceeds certain number (212). Does anyone know what is causing this problem and how to resolve it?

Thanks, 
Luning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a 32bit integer overflow - i.e. `213*213*213*213` it's greater than the maximum 32 bit integer. You should use 64bit integers as your indexes (`long` or more explicitly `int64_t`).

Why are you converting your memoryview to a pointer though? You'll won't have gained much speed and you'll have lost any information about the shape (for example, you have an assumption that all the dimensions are the same) and you could let Cython handle the multi-dimensional indexing for you. It would be much better to make the `tei` argument a memoryview rather than a pointer.